Normalization and homogenization of inequalities
I'm quite new to the topic of inequalities and having a lot of troubles with understanding these techniques, can someone please clarify some things to me?
First of all, if some inequality is homogeneous, what assumptions can I make without loss of generality? I know a+b+c=1, a+b+c=3, so I can assume WLOG that a+b+c=k for positive integer k, right? What about abc=1? Is it just abc=1 or abc=k? Are there any other assumptions I can make? Can I combine them? What about a >= b >= c? It seems like this inequality is about rearrangement inequality, not normalization or homogenization, right?
Thanks in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
